# No variants found for 'app'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists: Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, project

I am getting an error in my project, `No variants found for 'app'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists.`
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXrnH.png)

Comment: It seems that your project hasn't app file. Check it.

Comment: The error message "No variants found for 'app'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists." does not explain much about the situation, but having the right System Image version that matches your app configuration should fix it.

I was able to fix this by downloading the correct platform version on AVD Manager.

Google codelab app targets v27 on build.gradle script, so you should install it before trying to run/test your downloaded app. If you downloaded Android Studio and only installed the latest API version, you will face this problem too. Make sure you have older versions.

Comment: This error went away for me after I added these environment variables: `ANDROID_HOME` and `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`

Answer (score -4, accepted):

your gradle build may have failed. make sure you have build.gradle, open the file and do Sync now, look for errors to tell you what is wrong.

Comment: I am getting an getting more error: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1upDHOkZwis3KkGAqk-94MrOfVaetlnVy/